# Grouping multiple bars in a bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have a bar chart where the height of each bar corresponds to the value of some variable over a single week, and consecutive bars correspond to consecutive weeks. However, I would like to label the x-axis by month. Here is a mock-up of what I have in mind:

[image: mock-up]

A few notes:

- In this mockup, each month consists of exactly four bars. In reality, that may not be the case, and a single bar may be split between two months.
- The "Now" months are bolded, as well as the word "Now" itself.
- The "Past" months have thinner bars than the "Now" months.

So my primary question is how to group the x-axis into months as displayed in the mock-up. Secondarily, if anyone wants to help me with the double-headed arrow labelled "Past" and "Now" and the uneven bar width, that would be great.

Here's some code with dummy data if anyone wants to use it:

```
library("ggplot2")
weeks <- c("06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/15/2019", "06/15/2019", "06/22/2019", "06/22/2019", "06/29/2019", "06/29/2019", "07/06/2019", "07/06/2019", "07/13/2019", "07/13/2019", "07/20/2019", "07/20/2019", "07/27/2019", "07/27/2019", "08/03/2019", "08/03/2019", "08/10/2019", "08/10/2019", "08/17/2019", "08/17/2019", "08/24/2019", "08/24/2019", "08/31/2019", "08/31/2019")
values <- c(29, 10, 27, 20, 36, 2, 23, 4, 17, 16, 20, 13, 27, 10, 29, 1, 26, 0, 19, 20, 27, 4, 16, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10)
types <- c("Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful")
df <- data.frame(Week=weeks, Value=values, Type=types)
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Week, y=Value, fill=Type))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Successful"="#89EEA8", "Unsuccessful"="#FE8081"))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this kind of what you were looking for? I think you're biggest problem is that your Week variable is a character instead of a date.

```
library("ggplot2")
weeks <- c("06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/08/2019", "06/15/2019", "06/15/2019", "06/22/2019", "06/22/2019", "06/29/2019", "06/29/2019", "07/06/2019", "07/06/2019", "07/13/2019", "07/13/2019", "07/20/2019", "07/20/2019", "07/27/2019", "07/27/2019", "08/03/2019", "08/03/2019", "08/10/2019", "08/10/2019", "08/17/2019", "08/17/2019", "08/24/2019", "08/24/2019", "08/31/2019", "08/31/2019")
values <- c(29, 10, 27, 20, 36, 2, 23, 4, 17, 16, 20, 13, 27, 10, 29, 1, 26, 0, 19, 20, 27, 4, 16, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10)
types <- c("Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful")
df <- data.frame(Week=lubridate::date(as.POSIXct(weeks, format = "%m/%d/%Y")), Value=values, Type=types)
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Week, y=Value, fill=Type))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Successful"="#89EEA8", "Unsuccessful"="#FE8081"))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
p + scale_x_date()
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. I'd like to clearly delineate the start and end of each month with tick marks (this is not accurately represented by the mock-up), and center the name of the months between the tick marks. I think the problem is that the starts/ends of the months will not generally line up with the edges or centers of any of the bars. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I just realized your suggestion is already kinda doing that. So I guess it just boils down to placing tick marks and moving the month names to be between the tick marks.

Comment: In other words, given that the first week begins on June 1st, I would like the left edge of that bar to coincide with the tick mark on the left end of "Jun." I hope that makes sense.

Comment: apologies small mistake in the previous code that I just updated. Let me know if what is there now is more inline with what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any difference in the output with your updated code.

Comment: Ok, so by adding position=position_nudge(x=3.15) inside geom_bar, I got the position of the bars to what I want. Now I just need to place the names of the months on the x-axis between the tick marks.

Comment: Oh, but now the relative composition of each bar ("Successful" vs. "Unsuccessful") is incorrect. No idea why...

Comment: what do you mean by place the names of the months on the x-axis between the tick marks, aren't the months already there?